# How to subtract 2 values from an API in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object `profile` that has property `Hours` and `SchedHours`. I am attempting a ternary operator that subtracts `Hours` from `SchedHours` if `Hours` is a greater value then `SchedHours`

For example: If hours = 8 and scheduled hours = 5 I am attempting to return 3; if hours is less than or equal to SchedHours return 0. At the moment hours is greater then SchedHours it returns NaN

Here is how the the object appears

```
Hours: 8
SchedHours: 5
```

ternary opertaor:

```
return profile.Hours <= profile.SchedHours? (
                        <Typography>0</Typography>
                    ) : (
                        <Typography>
                            {profile.Hours - profile.SchedHours}
                        </Typography>
                    );
```

Comment: In your object you have `SchedShiftHours` but then you use `SchedHours` in the function. Is that correct?

Comment: Have you verified that both `profile.Hours` and `profile.SchedHours` are of type number? I'd expect the NaN in a case where one of them is undefined.

Comment: That was a typo, fixed.

Comment: Whats returning "NaN"?

Comment: I am receiving NaN when Hours and SchedHours do not equal each other. I displaying the text on a table

Answer (score 0):

If you are just returning `0` if they are equal, then you don't need the ternary at all. Are you sure you don't want to check that its less than?

```
<Typography>
  {profile.SchedHours < profile.Hours ? profile.Hours - profile.SchedHours: 0}
</Typography>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the subtraction when non-equal, and 0 when equal, that would be the same thing as always returning subtraction.

That aside, it looks like you were headed in the right direction:

```
> a = 0
> b = 1
> a === b ? 0 : a-b
-1
```

And when they're equal:

```
> a = 0
> b = 0
> a === b ? 0 : a-b
0
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - check out if both are number because if one of them was string then will produce a problem

can you explain more and can you try something like this :

```js
return profile.Hours === profile.SchedHours? (
                        <Typography>0</Typography>
                    ) : (
                        <Typography>
                            {(profile.Hours - profile.SchedHours)}
                        </Typography>
                    );
```

and the problem could be from Typography Component.

Comment: i think the problem is not the Typography Component

Comment: Both are returning a number, still getting a NaN display

Comment: what's Typography Component, I just tried that with h1 and works fine